# Making it simpler to install multiple plugins from Eclipse Marketplace?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-marketplace

We have found that we need to have multiple plugins (at least egit and m2e-wtp) installed from Eclipse Marketplace every time we unpack a fresh copy of Eclipse Juno SR1.

Is there a simple way to tell Eclipse to do this?  Perhaps an umbrella plugin available inhouse which depends on the marketplace or a magic file to copy into the unpacked distribution?

Windows-only will be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two easy ways:

1. Package your own Eclipse version that have all the plugins and configuration you would want and use that instead of downloading. Programs exists that helps out with this if you want more control of the installations; [SDC](http://www.genuitec.com/sdc/) and [Yoxos](https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/)
2. Use the Eclipse director. You would create a script that starts upp Eclipse Director and it would download and install the plugins of your choice. 
   [Read more about it here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html)
3. Create a shared installation. Just download and set up Eclipse once and then everyone can use the same installation. [Read more here](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/multi_user_installs.html).

Comment: The director looks like what I might be looking for.

Comment: What about an umbrella plugin with the ones we need as dependencies?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sure, that would work too. But that would require you to make that plugin, maintain it, create an update site for it etc.

Comment: One alternative if the user base is large and you want to automate things: Install Eclipse director on all users machines, setup a director script that downloads and installs the Eclipse package you want and then it installs all additional plugins.
Would also make reinstallations very simple.

Answer (score 2):

There is an additional three-minute-solution: From one of your existing installations, select `File -> Export -> Install -> Installed software items to file`. Put the resulting file on a share and import it in every new installation using the same menu items under File -> Import.

This is not as automated as in the other suggestions, but you have to do only one manual step per installation now, not one per plugin.

Answer (score 1):

create a target platform and add  corresponding update site under target plateform.
every time  download new eclipse set against target

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?pde version="3.8"?><target name="<product name>" sequenceNumber="2">
<locations>
<location path="${eclipse_home}" type="Directory"/>
<location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true"     includeMode="planner"includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
<unit id="org.apache.derby" version="10.5.1.1_v201108232300"/>
<unit id="org.apache.log4j" version="1.2.15.v201012070815"/>
<repository location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20120526062928/repository/"/>
</location>
</locations>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that Kepler makes it easier to install multiple plugins in general. When you click 'Install' for a software, the next screen has an 'Install More' button where the 'Back' button would normally be